# Error : Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less accessible than method '

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I get this error

> Error 6   Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'HomePage.Models.SaveResult' is less accessible than method 'HomePage.Models.CarDataStore.SaveFillup(HomePage.Models.Fillup, System.Action)'

and this is the class :

```
 private const string CAR_PHOTO_DIR_NAME = "FuelTracker";
    private const string CAR_PHOTO_FILE_NAME = "CarPhoto.jpg";
    private const string CAR_PHOTO_TEMP_FILE_NAME = "TempCarPhoto.jpg";
    private const string CAR_KEY = "FuelTracker.Car";
    private static readonly IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings =
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    private static Car _car;

    public static event EventHandler CarUpdated;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the car data, loading the data from isolated storage
    /// (if there is any saved data) on the first access. 
    /// </summary>
    public static Car Car 
    { 
        get
        {
            if (_car == null)
            {
                if (appSettings.Contains(CAR_KEY))
                {
                    _car = (Car)appSettings[CAR_KEY];
                    _car.Picture = GetCarPhoto(CAR_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
                }
                else
                {
                    _car = new Car
                    {
                        FillupHistory = new ObservableCollection<Fillup>()
                    };
                }
            }
            return _car;
        }
        set
        {
            _car = value;
            NotifyCarUpdated();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the car data to isolated storage. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="errorCallback">The action to execute if the 
    /// storage attempt fails.</param>
    public static void SaveCar(Action errorCallback)
    {
        try
        {
            appSettings[CAR_KEY] = Car;
            appSettings.Save();
            DeleteTempCarPhoto();
            SaveCarPhoto(CAR_PHOTO_FILE_NAME, Car.Picture, errorCallback);
            NotifyCarUpdated();
        }
        catch (IsolatedStorageException)
        {
            errorCallback();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the car data from isolated storage and resets the Car property.
    /// </summary>
    public static void DeleteCar()
    {
        appSettings.Remove(CAR_KEY);
        appSettings.Save();
        Car = null;
        DeleteCarPhoto();
        DeleteTempCarPhoto();
        NotifyCarUpdated();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the temporary car photo from isolated storage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The temporary car photo.</returns>
    public static BitmapImage GetTempCarPhoto()
    {
        return GetCarPhoto(CAR_PHOTO_TEMP_FILE_NAME);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the temporary car photo to isolated storage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="carPicture">The image to save.</param>
    /// <param name="errorCallback">The action to execute if the storage
    /// attempt fails.</param>
    public static void SaveTempCarPhoto(BitmapImage carPicture, 
        Action errorCallback)
    {
        SaveCarPhoto(CAR_PHOTO_TEMP_FILE_NAME, carPicture, errorCallback);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the car photo from isolated storage.
    /// </summary>
    private static void DeleteCarPhoto()
    {
        DeletePhoto(CAR_PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the temporary car photo from isolated storage.
    /// </summary>
    public static void DeleteTempCarPhoto()
    {
        DeletePhoto(CAR_PHOTO_TEMP_FILE_NAME);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the photo with the specified file name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">The name of the photo file to delete.</param>
    private static void DeletePhoto(String fileName)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(CAR_PHOTO_DIR_NAME, fileName);
            if (store.FileExists(path)) store.DeleteFile(path);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the specified car photo from isolated storage.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">The filename of the photo to get.</param>
    /// <returns>The requested photo.</returns>
    private static BitmapImage GetCarPhoto(string fileName)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(CAR_PHOTO_DIR_NAME, fileName);

            if (!store.FileExists(path)) return null;

            using (var stream = store.OpenFile(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(stream);
                return image;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the specified car photo to isolated storage using the 
    /// specified filename.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">The filename to use.</param>
    /// <param name="carPicture">The image to save.</param>
    /// <param name="errorCallback">The action to execute if the storage
    /// attempt fails.</param>
    private static void SaveCarPhoto(string fileName, BitmapImage carPicture,
        Action errorCallback)
    {
        if (carPicture == null) return;
        try
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(carPicture);
                var path = Path.Combine(CAR_PHOTO_DIR_NAME, fileName);

                if (!store.DirectoryExists(CAR_PHOTO_DIR_NAME))
                {
                    store.CreateDirectory(CAR_PHOTO_DIR_NAME);
                }

                using (var stream = store.OpenFile(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IsolatedStorageException)
        {
            errorCallback();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the specified Fillup and then, if it is valid, adds it to
    /// Car.FillupHistory collection. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fillup">The fill-up to save.</param>
    /// <param name="errorCallback">The action to execute if the storage
    /// attempt fails.</param>
    /// <returns>The validation results.</returns>
    public static SaveResult SaveFillup(Fillup fillup, Action errorCallback)
    {
        var lastReading =
            Car.FillupHistory.Count > 0 ?
            Car.FillupHistory.First().OdometerReading :
            Car.InitialOdometerReading;
        fillup.DistanceDriven = fillup.OdometerReading - lastReading;

        var saveResult = new SaveResult();
        var validationResults = fillup.Validate();
        if (validationResults.Count > 0)
        {
            saveResult.SaveSuccessful = false;
            saveResult.ErrorMessages = validationResults;
        }
        else
        {
            Car.FillupHistory.Insert(0, fillup);
            saveResult.SaveSuccessful = true;
            SaveCar(delegate { 
                saveResult.SaveSuccessful = false; 
                errorCallback(); });
        }
        return saveResult;
    }

    private static void NotifyCarUpdated()
    {
        var handler = CarUpdated;
        if (handler != null) handler(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and what's the problem? If you intend the external code to call `SaveFillup`, make the `SaveResult` public, otherwise make `SaveFillup` internal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class `SaveResult`  wherever it is declared, either needs to have it's access modifier changed to public, since the method is public, or the method's access modifier needs to be changed to whatever access modifier the class is defined as (or to a lower scope)

Answer (score 4):

Your class `SaveResult` is probably internal (default accessor for classes when no one is defined). Make it public to solve this problem.

Comment: Or return through an interface.